# Tinymce: Adding custom HTML to the toolbar

Tags: tinymce-4

I'm wanting to extend the tinymce toolbar with a font family selector that displays the font family names styled with that font-family.  To do this I need to wrap each font name markup with a class or inline css.  I've scoured the tinymce API documentation and am struggling to find a way to add custom HTML in an menu item.

The closest I've gotten is an un-styled button that opens a panel with a custom HTML selector, but it's not ideal.  I'd really like to add an select directly to the toolbar that is styled with the font families.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. It doesn't use the toolbar, but instead adds an extra `menubar` item with custom `menuitems`.

HTML

```
<form>
 <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

JavaScript

It works by adding menuItems to the menu. We can then provide the `classes` option to the menuitem. This allows us to target each menu item separately via css class selectors. E.g. If we supply `classes: "monospace"`. TinyMCE converts this into `.mce-monospace` as the class selector. However tinymces css rules will override unless you select a bigger css precedence.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  menu: {
    mynewmenu: {
      title: 'Select Font Family',
      items: 'arial | monospace | timesnew'
    }
  },

  menubar: 'mynewmenu',

  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.addMenuItem('arial', {
      text: 'Arial',
      classes: "arial",
      context: 'mynewmenu',
      onclick: function() {
        alert('yey!');
      }
    });

    editor.addMenuItem('monospace', {
      text: 'Monospace',            
      classes: "monospace",
      context: 'mynewmenu',
      onclick: function() {
        alert('yey!');
      }
    });
    editor.addMenuItem('timesnew', {
      text: 'Times New Roman',          
      classes: "timesnew",
      context: 'mynewmenu',
      onclick: function() {
        alert('yey!');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

CSS

This is how I got the style to override via css.

```
.mce-menu-item.mce-monospace > span {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: olive;
}
.mce-menu-item.mce-arial > span{
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
}

.mce-menu-item.mce-timesnew > span{
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  color: green;
}
```

Notice if you just use `.mce-monospace > span` The precedence value is not big enough, while with `.mce-menu-item.mce-monospace > span` has a bigger precedence value and overrides tinymces css.

Have a look at this example [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/vxarnahy/3/)

Comment: Hey @PalinDrome555, while I was hoping to use toolbar button that would show the currently selected font family, this is a really creative work around.  Thanks.  I'll wait to see if anyone knows of a more direct solution before accepting yours.

Comment: @Matt Dietsche I think I got what you need here. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/1kpt0aay/5/).